# Why do I need to specify a name in spark_read_csv() and also assign it into an object?

Tags: r, apache-spark, dry, sparklyr

If I understand the usuage correctly (if not please correct me) `sparklyr::spark_read_csv()` should be used like so:

```
my_table <- spark_read_csv(sc = my_connnection, 
name = "my_table", 
path = "path/to/my/data")
```

This seems to me (I think wrongly) to violate DRY. I am naming my object twice, once in the assignment of the output of the function, and again in the supplied argument to `name`, which has no defaults and is "The name to assign to the newly generated table."

Why do I 'name' my output from the function twice? Is there a 'spark' object that takes the `name` argument of the function behind the scenes? Is there a reason to name them differently, or the same?

Comment: I believe the string you pass to "my_table" will be the name of the registered table in spark, accessible via sql (e.g. SELECT * FROM); whereas the return from the function is the DataFrame instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to assign it to an object. You can just access it by name:

```
dplyr::tbl(sc, "some_name")
```

or

```
sc %>% spark_session() %>% invoke("sql", "SELECT * FROM my_table")
```

but in general, it is a matter of design. `sparklyr` + `dplyr` combination treats Spark like a database. When you call `spark_read_csv` it create a temporary table under the `name` which can be used by the `dplyr` backend,

Unless you plan it by name you can use a random string (to avoid name clashes).

Comment: This looks like what I was thinking of, could you possibly include if there is any reason to name them differently or the same in your answer please?